# Sample size for F1 score

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, binary-data, diagnostic

I am developing a binary test and will be evaluating it based on the F1-score against a perfect reference standard. I want to calculate the sample size I'd need to have 80% power to be 95% confident my test has an F1 score of 0.95. I could not find anything online that I could understand on how to do this. I have extremely limited statistics knowledge and do most of my coding in R.

Comment: In order to do this, you need to have in mind a difference that is not practically important. For instance, does it matter if your score is $0.94?$ $0.945?$ // Why use $F_1$ score instead of a different metric? Is it an issue of class imbalance?

Comment: a difference of 0.3 around 0.95 would probably be unimportant. Yeah, for my tests I would usually use sensitivity and specificity, but in this case I will have no true negative, so I thought the F1-score would be suitable.

Comment: You have no true negatives? Then why not call everything a positive?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by why not call everything a positive? My test call things positive based on a predefined metric, so I would have true positives, false positives, false negatives, and the F1 score incorporates all of those.

Comment: If there are no true negatives, then why would you ever predict anything as a negative? Predicting something as a negative guarantees that it will be wrong.